# Assign and use mysql user variables in select clause

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with EID as primary key, (it is a varchar and contains some details) and uploadtime as a datetime column. I wanted the result from this table as :

```
substr(eid,5,5) as machine | count(eid) in group(grouped by machine) as packets | AvgDelay (as shown in SQL code) | packets * AvgDelay as Penalty
```

But the last column is always null. The SQL I used is:

```
SELECT substr(eid, 5, 5) AS machine,
@packetcount: = count(*) AS packets,
@avg_delay: = round(avg(DATEDIFF(IF (STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL, CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d')), STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(eid, 15, 8), '%Y%m%d') ) ) ) AS AvgDelay, 
@packetcount * @avg_delay AS Penalty 
FROM eidreport
WHERE uploadtime IS NOT NULL
OR DATEDIFF(IF (STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL, CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d')), STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(eid, 15, 8), '%Y%m%d') ) >= 100 
GROUP BY machine
```

[Here is the link for SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fa45/1)

Where am I wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the issue here in the `GROUP BY` statement. I think `@packetcount: = count(*)` calculates after grouping but `@packetcount * @avg_delay` before so they are undefined in this moment.

Try to use subquery like this:

```
SELECT *,
packets * AvgDelay AS Penalty

FROM
(
select substr(eid,5,5) as machine,count(*) as packets,
round(avg(DATEDIFF(IF(STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL, CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d')),
                      STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(eid, 15, 8),'%Y%m%d')))) AS AvgDelay
from eidreport
where uploadtime is not null or
DATEDIFF(
  IF(STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL, CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d')),
  STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(eid, 15, 8),'%Y%m%d')) >= 100
group by machine
) as T
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/6fa45/16)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Why using subqueries when not necessary:

```
SELECT
    SUBSTR(eid,5,5) machine,
    COUNT(1) packets,
    ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(IF (STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL,
                        CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d')),
                        STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(eid, 15, 8), '%Y%m%d') ) ) ) AvgDelay,
    COUNT(1) * ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(IF (STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL,
                        CURDATE(), STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d')),
                        STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(eid, 15, 8), '%Y%m%d') ) ) ) Penalty
FROM
    eidreport
WHERE uploadtime IS NOT NULL
OR DATEDIFF(IF (STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d') IS NULL, CURDATE(),
            STR_TO_DATE(uploadtime, '%Y-%m-%d')),
            STR_TO_DATE(SUBSTR(eid, 15, 8), '%Y%m%d') ) >= 100 
GROUP BY machine
```

The optimers evaluates identical expresions only once